# Stack columns if browser size is small

Tags: angularjs, css, angular-material, material-ui

I have 2 columns on my page... my issue is that I want the right column to stack underneath my left column if browser size is made smaller. I am using angular material but don't mind using custom styling to fix this. Any help will be appreciated.

HTML:

```
<div layout="row" layout-align="center center" flex>
    <section layout="row">
      <div id="nav" flex="20" layout="column" layout-align="space-around">
        <md-calendar class="fixed-calendar" ng-model="myDate"></md-calendar>
      </div>
      <div id="content" flex>
        <h2>Right Column</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas maxime officia aliquam nesciunt debitis quam optio odio soluta corrupti, mollitia, possimus iure quos nostrum eius nam. Aperiam voluptatum voluptate unde.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas maxime officia aliquam nesciunt debitis quam optio odio soluta corrupti, mollitia, possimus iure quos nostrum eius nam. Aperiam voluptatum voluptate unde.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas maxime officia aliquam nesciunt debitis quam optio odio soluta corrupti, mollitia, possimus iure quos nostrum eius nam. Aperiam voluptatum voluptate unde.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas maxime officia aliquam nesciunt debitis quam optio odio soluta corrupti, mollitia, possimus iure quos nostrum eius nam. Aperiam voluptatum voluptate unde.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas maxime officia aliquam nesciunt debitis quam optio odio soluta corrupti, mollitia, possimus iure quos nostrum eius nam. Aperiam voluptatum voluptate unde.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas maxime officia aliquam nesciunt debitis quam optio odio soluta corrupti, mollitia, possimus iure quos nostrum eius nam. Aperiam voluptatum voluptate unde.</p>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.datepickerdemoBasicUsage md-content {
    padding-bottom: 200px; }

.datepickerdemoBasicUsage .validation-messages {
    font-size: 11px;
    color: darkred;
    margin: 10px 0 0 25px; }

.fixed-calendar {
  width: 340px;
  height: 340px;
  display: block;
}

.fixed-calendar .md-calendar-scroll-mask {
  width: 340px !important;
}

.fixed-calendar .md-virtual-repeat-scroller {
  width: 340px !important;
  height: 308px;
  overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3zz4nd9z/1/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this on your parent `layout="column" layout-gt-xs="row"`

```
<div ng-app="sandbox">
  <div>
    <section layout="column" layout-gt-xs="row">
      <div id="nav" flex>
        <md-calendar class="fixed-calendar" ng-model="myDate"></md-calendar>
      </div>
      <div id="content" flex>
        <h2>Right Column</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas maxime officia aliquam nesciunt debitis quam optio odio soluta corrupti, mollitia, possimus iure quos nostrum eius nam. Aperiam voluptatum voluptate unde.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas maxime officia aliquam nesciunt debitis quam optio odio soluta corrupti, mollitia, possimus iure quos nostrum eius nam. Aperiam voluptatum voluptate unde.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas maxime officia aliquam nesciunt debitis quam optio odio soluta corrupti, mollitia, possimus iure quos nostrum eius nam. Aperiam voluptatum voluptate unde.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas maxime officia aliquam nesciunt debitis quam optio odio soluta corrupti, mollitia, possimus iure quos nostrum eius nam. Aperiam voluptatum voluptate unde.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas maxime officia aliquam nesciunt debitis quam optio odio soluta corrupti, mollitia, possimus iure quos nostrum eius nam. Aperiam voluptatum voluptate unde.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas maxime officia aliquam nesciunt debitis quam optio odio soluta corrupti, mollitia, possimus iure quos nostrum eius nam. Aperiam voluptatum voluptate unde.</p>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

This says stack child elements into a column. 
Then if the browser width gets to greater than or equal xs (>= 600px), make child elements into a row.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xjdtp63x/)